# AVPlayer provide wrong currenttime and duration iOS when seek the video many times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I use use AVPlayer to implement a custom player.

Some video playerItem provide the current time and wrong duration. After to seek time use slide to seek time many times. Call the API
When I seek to zero, some video can not be precisely seeked.

```
      [self.player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(time, NSEC_PER_SEC)
      toleranceBefore:CMTimeMake(1, 1)
      toleranceAfter:CMTimeMake(1, 1)
      completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {
         if (finished) {
             IVCLogV(@"seek finish!");
         }
         else
         {
             IVCLogV(@"seek interrupted");
         }
         if (completionHandle) {
             completionHandle(finished);
         }
     }];
```

I change the codes according the mediaTime.timeScale. Now I discover **the video stream have changed the video duration and current time** after several play.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the Timescale of the media being played matches with your timescale. I can see you have used NSEC_PER_SEC as timescale. You may have to scale your CMTime input to seelTo method.

```
CMTime timeAccordingToMediaTimescale = CMTimeConvertScale(time, mediaTime.timescale, CMTimeRoundingMethod);
```

Comment: thank you. i change the codes according the mediaTime.timeScale.  Now I discover the **video stream have changed the video duration and current time** after several play.